# How to run Spring Integration

Tags: maven, spring-integration

I have downloaded spring integration from "http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/spring-integration-a-lightweight-integration-approach.html#comment-51110"

I an using STS, I have downloaded the Spring Sample then imported the sample File-->Maven-->Existing Maven Project then try to run it on the server.

Its showing "HTTP Status 404 - /spring-integration/" Error

Can someone help me how to run the Spring Integration Project.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with that blog post; I suggest you start with the [project page](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/); it has links to documentation, getting started guide and lots of samples.